# Filtration and measurability of a process over countable subset of $[0,1]$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Let $\{X_t\}_{t\in[0,T]}$ be a stochastic process and $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\in[0,T]}$ its natural filtration.  Show that for any $\mathcal{F}_1$-measurable r.v. $Y$, there exists and countable $S\subset[0,1]$ such that $Y(\omega)=Y(\omega')$ as soon as $X_t(\omega)=X_t(\omega')$, $\forall t\in S$.

I am really stumped and confused by this question, so any help is most appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

By [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2058208/measurability-of-a-random-varaiable-over-sigma-field-generated-by-a-countable-fa), there exists a countable subset $S$ of $[0,1]$ such that 
$\sigma(Y)\subset \sigma\left(X_s,s\in S\right)$. Write $S=\{s_n, n\in\mathbb N\}$.  By [the Doob-Dynkin lemma](https://yoo2080.wordpress.com/2014/09/22/doob-dynkin-lemma-for-probability-space/), there exists a function $f\colon\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}\to\mathbb R$ such that $Y=f\left(X_{s_n}\right)$. If $X_{s_n}(\omega)    =X_{s_n}(\omega')$ then $Y(\omega)=Y'(\omega')$.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think the Doob-Dynkin lemma would apply as I wasn't sure how you define a measure space around $\mathbb{R}^\mahbb{N}$. Do you consider $\mathbb{R}^\mahbb{N}$ a a topological vector space and take the Borel-algebra to be generated by that topology? Would appreciate if you could help me fill in the missing details there. Thanks.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ to fix the typo.